# How to get list of port name and port number using pymongo client

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

how to get hostname and port number using pymongo client?
I tried the client.HOST and client.PORT  but its returning default value localhost,27017
Also, I tried the client.host its returning MongoDB client object as below

```
MongoClient(host=['mgdb-raspoc-npd2-1.xxxxx.com:27066', 'mgdb-raspoc-npd3-1.xxxxx.com:27066', 'mgdb-raspoc-npd1-1.xxxxx.com:27066'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, serverselectiontimeoutms=6000, replicaset='raspoc', authsource='admin')
```

I am looking for a list of hostnames and port numbers as below

```
['mgdb-raspoc-npd2-1.xxxxx.com:27066', 'mgdb-raspoc-npd3-1.xxxxx.com:27066', 'mgdb-raspoc-npd1-1.xxxxx.com:27066']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be computed from the `primary`, `secondaries` and `arbiters` property of `pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient`. *e.g.*

```py
from itertools import chain
//...
seeds = [
    (host, port)
    for host, port in chain([client.primary], client.secondaries, client.arbiters)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use client.nodes returns frozenset (element of frozenset is tuple of hostname and port).

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0-p0odn.mongodb.net/test')
print(client.nodes) #modify as you need
```